# What does the edX course Progress Bar Color code signifies?

Tags: edx

I have been going through an edX course and have been tracking my progress to remain self-motivated. I am observing various color code for each module. I earlier thought they signify my performance but that doesn't seems so. I have also looked for the meaning of these legends at https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-guide-for-students/en/latest/SFD_check_progress.html#grading-chart
but could not find any indicators.I would like to know the significance of the Bar Color of the progress chart.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each color signifies a different assignment type. For example, in your case, you have assignments of type M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, PCT and PST.

Each type will have a color in this order: light red, dark red, light grey, dark grey.

It is just a way to make it easier for you to distinguish between your grades.

Here it is in the code: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/master/lms/templates/courseware/progress_graph.js#L43